# regex match a pattern but replace with different values

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like `"${f1}:blah blah ${f2} blah ${f1}"`. I have a `Map<String, String>` with `"f1"`, `"f2"` as the keys.

I want to replace `"${f1}"`, `"${f2}"` etc in the string with the corresponding values given in the map.

How do I do that in Java? I have hardly any experience with Java regex.

Comment: Start by reading.  Then move to trying.  When you get stuck, give us a specific example.  Good luck.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This type of question has already been asked at SO. you need to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605716/java-regular-expression-find-and-replace).

Comment: The others suggested a loop with replacement. That seems like too expensive. This link on the other hand finds out all the ${f1} ${f2} etc and replace them accordingly. So you don't end up traversing the same string multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
for (Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
            String test="${f1}:blah blah ${f2} blah ${f1}";
            System.out.println(test.replace("${f2}", e.getValue()).replace("${f1}", e.getKey()));

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do it this way

```
    String str = "${f1}:blah blah ${f2} blah ${f1}";
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put("\\$\\{f1\\}", "xxxx");
    map.put("\\$\\{f2\\}", "yyyy");

    for (Map.Entry entry: map.entrySet()) {
        str = str.replaceAll((String)entry.getKey(), (String)entry.getValue());
    }

    System.out.println(str);
```

The output is:

```
xxxx:blah blah yyyy blah xxxx
```