# Java regex - Replace "x^2" with "x²" but NOT "x^27" with "x²7"

Tags: java, regex, replace, match

I got a string of an equation where I want to replace all occurrences of the scheme "x^2" with "x²".

My code:

```
String equation = "x^2";
equation = equation.replace("^2", "\u00B2");  // u00b2 is unicode for '²'

System.out.println(equation);
```

This works for "x^2" but for example **"x^25"** I'm getting the string **"x²5"**, but in such a case I want it to stay the same "x^25".

Another example:

> "x^2 + 6x" -> "x² + 6x"   // ... x squared
>
> "x^28 + 6x" -> "x^28 + 6x"  // ... x to the power of 28

Thank you!

EDIT:
The solution from **"Mshnik"** works perfectly, even with a custom character like "y^2" instead of "x^2", thanks!

Comment: Are there any cases where there could be something like x^3y?

Comment: @LukaJacobowitz When I have got a solution I want to use it to also replace "x^3" with "x³". My equation will not contain a second variable "y".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a regex that will match `2` in `x^2`, the `2` in `a^2+...` but not the `2` in `x^20`:

```
(?<=\w)\^2(?![0-9.])
```

Specifically:

- `(?<= <EXP>)` is a positive lookbehind on `<EXP>`, More explanation [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- `\w` matches any alphabetic character, upper or lower case.
- `\^` matches the `^` character literally
- `2` matches the `2` character literally
- `(?! <EXP>)` is a negative lookahead on `<EXP>` More explanation [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).
- `[0-9.]` matches all numbers and decimals, like `58` and `3.14`.

Thus all together it matches the `2` that is preceded by `x^` and **isn't** followed by a digit.

With that, you can use java's `Pattern` class to find and rebuild a string with the new `²`. More on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605716/java-regular-expression-find-and-replace)

Note that in order to get a backslash into a java regex, you need the literal backslash character represented by `\\`. Thus the final result looks like `(?<=\\w)\\^2(?![0-9.])`.

Comment: Thank you, **this works** perfectly! :)
PS: I'd had to add a back slash like "x\\^2(?![0-9])" for java.

The link you provided is also very helpful, so I can replace other symbols like "³" too.

Comment: you're welcome! I'll add an edit specifying that for posterity. I'd love that green check once you can

Comment: @Mshnik Is there a short way to match instead of x every possible character of the alphabet?

Comment: @Mshnik The character class `\w` is more appropriate here (it will also find `é^2`, should anyone ever want to use that variable name), also, `[0-9]` is equivalent to `\d`.

Comment: @Mshnik Now i use `equation.replaceAll("\\w\\^2(?![0-9])", "x\u00B2");` but this replaces "y²" with "x²". Do you know how to fix this in a short way? Or is it only possible using a Pattern and so on..?

Comment: @trinity420 Now only matches the `2` in the expression

Comment: @Mshnik Thank you, it nearly works, but the output for "x^2" is "x^²". Can you fix this?

Comment: Yes, **this works perfectly!** Thank you very much for your work and the detailed specific explanation of every part of the solution!