# Replace all occurrences of a substring, one at a time

Tags: java, string

I have the following method which replaces all occurrences of a `{TIMESTAMP}` substring with the value returned by `String.valueOf(System.nanoTime())`, the intention is to get a different time mark per substring occurrence, but it results in all substrings being replaced by just the same value.

```
class StringUtils {
    private static String resolveTimestamp(String s) {
        String timestamp = "\\{TIMESTAMP}";
        return s.replaceAll(timestamp, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
}

class Sample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringUtils.resolveTimestamp("{TIMESTAMP}, {TIMESTAMP}, {TIMESTAMP}")
    }
}

// The execution of the code above would result in:
// 241170886964203, 241170886964203, 241170886964203

// But I want to get this:
// 241733154573329, 241734822930540, 241751957270934
```

I would like to know which is the best way of doing what I want, as there are several ways of doing that coming to my mind right now:

- A loop with `s.matches(timestamp)` as condition to iterate over each occurrence of the substring, and `s.replaceFirst(timestamp, String.valueOf(System.nanoTime()))` to perform the replacement inside the loop.
- Use the substring to explode the string into several chunks with `s.split(timestamp)`, and iterate over the chunks joining each pair with the value returned by `String.valueOf(System.nanoTime()))`
- Probably some other choices

NOTE: Please be aware that this is not the same problem addressed [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605716). There they need to replace several occurrences of a fixed pattern with just the same value, while I need to replace several occurrences of the same substring, each one by a different value calculated at runtime.

Comment: What different value do you want?  `currentTimeMillis()` is likely to return the same value when you call it over a short period of time.

Comment: Unless you are replacing a large number timestamps (tens of thousands) in a single string, it will make no difference if you do them one at a time or all at once.  It will all happen within much less than a millisecond so you'll get the same value anyway. Sometimes you'll get values differing by 1 in the last place if you happen to cross a millisecond boundary.   I think this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java regular expression find and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605716/java-regular-expression-find-and-replace)

Comment: "There they need to replace several occurrences of a fixed pattern with just the same value" no, they are replacing each occurrence of match with result of `currentTimeMillis()` which is invoked once per loop so it can give different values.

Comment: I've edited the question and I think it's much clearer now

Comment: @markspace you're right, good point! I've replaced `currentTimeMillis()` with `nanoTime()`

Comment: You have yet to explain why and how you expect each replacement to contain a distinct timestamp.

Comment: @shmosel I don't know what do you mean. I think now it's clear enough, to get a different timestamp you just have to call `System.nanoTime()` several times, not just once when passing the returned value to `s.replaceAll(timestamp, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))`.

Comment: There's no guarantee that calling `nanoTime()` several times will yield distinct values.

Comment: @shmosel sure, in that case, I would wrap it in a method which receives the previous "timestamp", and call `nanoTime()` until it returns a different value. My question is about the proper way of performing the replacement, not how to obtain the timestamp

Comment: Then it's not really a timestamp, is it? In fact, `nanoTime()` doesn't return a unix timestamp at all. You may as well use a simple incrementer. Until you explain what you're really trying to do, there's a good chance we're chasing an XY Problem (as @JimGarrison said) which would be a waste of our time and yours.

Comment: @shmosel You're right. Sorry for the inconvenience :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use String.replaceFirst:

```
private static String resolveTimestamp(String s) {
    String timestamp = "\\{TIMESTAMP}";

    while(s.matches(timestamp)) {
       s = s.replaceFirst(timestamp, String.valueOf(System.nanoTime()));
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: It is likely more efficient to use [`Matcher.appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-) followed by an `appendTail`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I didn't know how this class works.

Comment: @baudsp I've edited the question to use `System.nanoTime()` instead of `currentTimeMillis()`, as the latter is really likely to return the same value for several calls. Could you edit your answer to be able to mark it as the solution? Thanks

Comment: @beni0888 I've done the change. But you can edit other people's answer, I wouldn't have minded if you had made the change yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like what you want to do is modify: `replaceAll` with `replaceFirst`
this way every time you'll call the method with the string - it will replace only the next occurrence:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String req = "\\{TIMESTAMP} \\{TIMESTAMP} \\{TIMESTAMP} \\{TIMESTAMP}";
    req = resolveTimestamp(req);
    req = resolveTimestamp(req);
    req = resolveTimestamp(req);
    req = resolveTimestamp(req);
    System.out.println("req = " + req);
}

private static String resolveTimestamp(String s) {
    String timestamp = "\\{TIMESTAMP}";
    return s.replaceFirst(timestamp, String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
req = \1510940324918 \1510940324921 \1510940324921 \1510940324921
```

**Comment**: you should consider using `System.nanoTime()` instead of `System.currentTimeMillis()` if you want better precision.

Comment: `System.nanoTime()` doesn't return a timestamp in the conventional sense. It starts at an arbitrary offset.

Comment: @shmosel you're right, I corrected "better accuracy" to "better precision".

Answer (score -1):

You need to call a method to return a random string within your replace all method.

```
str.replaceAll("timestamp", randomTimestamp());

private String randomTimestamp() {
    Random rand = new Random(); 
    int randomNumber= rand.nextInt(1000);
    return String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis() + randomNumber);
}
```